# Why updating the elements in a Numpy array based on the elements from another array turns all values to zero?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Say I have two Numpy 1D arrays `a` and `b` of the same size.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.full(10, -10)
b = np.random.rand(10)
print(a)
# [-10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10]
print(b)
# [0.8725654  0.48385524 0.67801994 0.30381863 0.95460565 0.73915384 0.38097293 0.4604181  0.91182102 0.33428477]
```

Now I want to update array `a` with the elements from array `b` based on some condition using a for loop, for example:

```
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    if x < b[i]:
        a[i] = b[i]
print(a)
# [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Why am I getting an array of all zeros instead of the values from array `b`?

Comment: check the `a.dtype`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `a = np.full(10, -10)` the data type is int32. Thus the values you assign from array b are rounded to 0. Just use:

```
a = np.full(10, -10, dtype=float)
```

and its should work.

Answer (score 1):

koxx answer is right, but I also advise you to do this operation using numpy methods rather than a for loop. This code should give you the same output:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.full(10, 0.5)
b = np.random.rand(10)
a = np.maximum(a, b)
```